# Grouped Stack Bar Chart using Google Chart

Tags: google-visualization, bar-chart

I want to create chart as this:

[Demo](http://bl.ocks.org/gencay/4629518)!

Any one know if we could draw this kind of chart using Google Chart?

Comment: Please read the section of the site on [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). In general, please try to provide all the information required in the post without having to go to an external site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Google's Code [Playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#bar_chart):

If you add "isStacked: true" to the options, you'll have your stacked bars.

Just change the options to:

```
// Create and draw the visualization.
new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
  draw(data,
       {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
        width:600, height:400,
        vAxis: {title: "Year"},
        hAxis: {title: "Cups"},
        isStacked: true}
);
```